# How does the distance in reciprocal lattice relate to distance in real lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, fourier-transform, geometry, crystals, lattice-model

Suppose a two-slap of silicon is the distance 'a' apart in real space. What is distance between them in reciprocal space.

Answer (score 0):

In real space, the independent variable is the position. Hence, you can define the distance as the difference between the two positions.

In reciprocal space, the independent variable is the wavenumber. Hence, you cannot calculate anymore the distance as the difference between the two positions. What you can do, is determining the difference between two wavenumbers (instead of two positions).

Mathematically, the Fourier transform of a shift 'a' between two identical functions $f(x)$ is given by:

$$\mathcal{F}(f(x)+f(x-a)) = F(k)+e^{-i\omega a} F(k) = (1+e^{-i\omega a}) F(k)$$

Here, $f(x)$ represents the Fourier transform of one single silicon slab.

Comment: Suppose in real space ∆x=a so what is ∆k in Fourier space?

Comment: When you have $\Delta x = a$ in real space, then your complete reciprocal space function will change. A shift in real space is a modulation with an exponential in reciprocal space.